# How to prove $f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}\cosh(x)\cos(y) \\ \sinh(x)\sin(y)\end{pmatrix}$ is bijective on neighbourhood of point $(\ln{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'm trying to prove that $f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}\cosh(x)\cos(y) \\ \sinh(x)\sin(y)\end{pmatrix}$ is a bijection on a neighbourhood of point $(\ln{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$.

I can't get $x_1=x_2,y_1=y_2$ from
$$
\begin{cases}
\cosh(x_1)\cos(y_1) = \cosh(x_2)\cos(y_2) \\
\sinh(x_1)\sin(y_1) = \sinh(x_2)\sin(y_2)
\end{cases}
$$
so that I can't prove the function is injective.

Comment: That's enough of a hint, thanks.